# MXNet - application of GANs to MNIST

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mxnet

So this question is about [GANs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661).

I am trying to do a trivial example for my own proof of concept; namely, generate images of hand written digits (MNIST). While most will approach this via deep convolutional gans (dgGANs), I am just trying to achieve this via the 1D array (i.e. instead of 28x28 gray-scale pixel values, a 28*28 1d array).

This [git repo](https://github.com/greydanus/mnist-gan) features a "vanilla" gans which treats the MNIST dataset as a 1d array of 784 values. Their output values look pretty acceptable so I wanted to do something similar.

## Import statements

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import nd, gluon, autograd
from mxnet.gluon import nn, utils
import numpy as np
import os
from math import floor
from random import random
import time
from datetime import datetime
import logging


ctx = mx.gpu()
np.random.seed(3)
```

## Hyper parameters

```
batch_size = 100
epochs = 100
generator_learning_rate = 0.001
discriminator_learning_rate = 0.001
beta1 = 0.5
latent_z_size = 100
```

## Load data

```
mnist = mx.test_utils.get_mnist()
# convert imgs to arrays
flattened_training_data = mnist["test_data"].reshape(10000, 28*28)
```

## define models

```
G = nn.Sequential()
with G.name_scope():
    G.add(nn.Dense(300, activation="relu"))
    G.add(nn.Dense(28 * 28, activation="tanh"))

D = nn.Sequential()
with D.name_scope():
    D.add(nn.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    D.add(nn.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    D.add(nn.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
    D.add(nn.Dense(2, activation="tanh"))


loss = gluon.loss.SoftmaxCrossEntropyLoss()
```

## init stuff

```
G.initialize(mx.init.Normal(0.02), ctx=ctx)
D.initialize(mx.init.Normal(0.02), ctx=ctx)
trainer_G = gluon.Trainer(G.collect_params(), 'adam', {"learning_rate": generator_learning_rate, "beta1": beta1})
trainer_D = gluon.Trainer(D.collect_params(), 'adam', {"learning_rate": discriminator_learning_rate, "beta1": beta1})

metric = mx.metric.Accuracy()
```

## dynamic plot (for juptyer notebook)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def dynamic_line_plt(ax, y_data, colors=['r', 'b', 'g'], labels=['Line1', 'Line2', 'Line3']):
    x_data = []
    y_max = 0
    y_min = 0
    x_min = 0
    x_max = 0
    for y in y_data:
        x_data.append(list(range(len(y))))
        if max(y) > y_max:
            y_max = max(y)
        if min(y) < y_min:
            y_min = min(y)

        if len(y) > x_max:
            x_max = len(y)

    ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)
    ax.set_xlim(x_min, x_max)

    if ax.lines:
        for i, line in enumerate(ax.lines):
            line.set_xdata(x_data[i])
            line.set_ydata(y_data[i])

    else:
        for i in range(len(y_data)):
            l = ax.plot(x_data[i], y_data[i], colors[i], label=labels[i])
        ax.legend()

    fig.canvas.draw()
```

## train

```
stamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M')
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


# arrays to store data for plotting
loss_D = nd.array([0], ctx=ctx)
loss_G = nd.array([0], ctx=ctx)
acc_d = nd.array([0], ctx=ctx)
labels = ['Discriminator Loss', 'Generator Loss', 'Discriminator Acc.']

%matplotlib notebook
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Loss')
dynamic_line_plt(ax, [loss_D.asnumpy(), loss_G.asnumpy(), acc_d.asnumpy()], labels=labels)


for epoch in range(epochs):
    tic = time.time()

    data_iter.reset()

    for i, batch in enumerate(data_iter):
        ####################################
        # Update Disriminator: maximize log(D(x)) + log(1-D(G(z)))
        ####################################

        # extract batch of real data
        data = batch.data[0].as_in_context(ctx)
        # add noise


        # Produce our noisey input to the generator
        latent_z = mx.nd.random_normal(0,1,shape=(batch_size, latent_z_size), ctx=ctx)


        # soft and noisy labels
#         real_label = mx.nd.ones((batch_size, ), ctx=ctx) * nd.random_uniform(.7, 1.2, shape=(1)).asscalar()
#         fake_label = mx.nd.ones((batch_size, ), ctx=ctx) * nd.random_uniform(0, .3, shape=(1)).asscalar()

#         real_label = nd.random_uniform(.7, 1.2, shape=(batch_size), ctx=ctx)
#         fake_label = nd.random_uniform(0, .3, shape=(batch_size), ctx=ctx)

        real_label = mx.nd.ones((batch_size, ), ctx=ctx)
        fake_label = mx.nd.zeros((batch_size, ), ctx=ctx)

        with autograd.record():
            # train with real data
            real_output = D(data)
            errD_real = loss(real_output, real_label)

           # train with fake data
            fake = G(latent_z)
            fake_output = D(fake.detach())
            errD_fake = loss(fake_output, fake_label)

            errD = errD_real + errD_fake
            errD.backward()

        trainer_D.step(batch_size)
        metric.update([real_label, ], [real_output,])        
        metric.update([fake_label, ], [fake_output,])


       ####################################
        # Update Generator: maximize log(D(G(z)))
        ####################################
        with autograd.record():
            output = D(fake)
            errG =  loss(output, real_label)
            errG.backward()

        trainer_G.step(batch_size)



        ####
        # Plot Loss
        ####
        # append new data to arrays
        loss_D = nd.concat(loss_D, nd.mean(errD), dim=0)
        loss_G = nd.concat(loss_G, nd.mean(errG), dim=0)
        name, acc = metric.get()
        acc_d = nd.concat(acc_d, nd.array([acc], ctx=ctx), dim=0)

        # plot array
        dynamic_line_plt(ax, [loss_D.asnumpy(), loss_G.asnumpy(), acc_d.asnumpy()], labels=labels)



    name, acc = metric.get()
    metric.reset()
    logging.info('Binary training acc at epoch %d: %s=%f' % (epoch, name, acc))
    logging.info('time: %f' % (time.time() - tic))
```

## output

```
img = G(mx.nd.random_normal(0,1,shape=(100, latent_z_size), ctx=ctx))[0].reshape((28, 28))
plt.imshow(img.asnumpy(),cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now this doesn't get nearly as good as the repo's example from above. Although fairly similar.

Thus I was wondering if you could take a look and figure out why:

1. the colors are inverted
2. why the results are sub par

I have been fiddling around with this trying a lot of various things to improve the results (I will list this in a second), but for the MNIST dataset this really shouldn't be needed.

Things I have tried (and I have also tried a host of combinations):

- increasing the generator network
- increasing the discriminator network
- using soft labeling
- using noisy labeling
- batch norm after every layer in the generator
- batch norm of the data
- normalizing all values between -1 and 1
- leaky relus in the generator
- drop out layers in the generator
- increased learning rate of discriminator compared to generator
- decreased learning rate of i compared to generator

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If you look into original dataset:

```
training_set = mnist["train_data"].reshape(60000, 28, 28)
plt.imshow(training_set[10,:,:], cmap='gray')
```

you will notice that the digits are white on a black background. So, technically speaking, your results are not inversed - they match the pattern of original images you used as a real data.

If you want to invert colors for visualization purposes, you can easily do that by changing the pallete to reversed one by adding '_r' (it works for all color palletes):

```
plt.imshow(img.asnumpy(), cmap='gray_r')
```

You also can play with ranges of colors by changing vmin and vmax parameters. They control how big the difference between colors should be. By default it is calculated automatically based on provided set.

2) "Why the results are sub par" - I think this is exactly the reason why the community started to use dcGANs. To me the results in the git repo you provided are quite noisy. Surely, they are different from what you receive, and you can achieve the same quality just by changing your activation functions from tanh to sigmoid as in the example on github:

```
G = nn.Sequential()
with G.name_scope():
    G.add(nn.Dense(300, activation="relu"))
    G.add(nn.Dense(28 * 28, activation="sigmoid"))

D = nn.Sequential()
with D.name_scope():
    D.add(nn.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    D.add(nn.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    D.add(nn.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
    D.add(nn.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid"))
```

[Sigmoid never goes below zero](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJ0YW5oKHgpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjMDA0MEZGIn0seyJ0eXBlIjowLCJlcSI6IjEvKDErZXhwKC14KSkiLCJjb2xvciI6IiNGRjA1MDUifSx7InR5cGUiOjEwMDAsIndpbmRvdyI6WyItNi41IiwiNi41IiwiLTEuMiIsIjEiXX1d) and it works better in this scenario. Here is a sample picture I get if I train updated model for 30 epochs (the rest of the hyperparameters are same).

[image]

If you decide to explore dcGAN to get even better results, take a look here - https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/unsupervised_learning/gan.html It is a well explained tutorial on how to build dcGAN with Mxnet and Gluon. By using dcGAN you will get way better results than that.